# Best way to to average duplicate properties in C++ vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

I have a `std::vector<PLY>` that holds a number of structs:

```
struct PLY {
    int x;
    int y;
    int greyscale;
}
```

Some of the PLY's could be duplicates in terms of their position `x` and `y` but not necessarily in terms of their `greyscale` value. What is the best way to find those (position-) duplicates and replace them with a single `PLY` instace which has a greyscale value that represents the average greyscale of all duplicates?

E.g: `PLY a{1,1,188}` is a duplicate of `PLY b{1,1,255}`. Same (x,y) position possibly different greyscale.

Comment: if they are exact duplicates, what do you mean by average of all duplicates?

Comment: If you can modify the vector, you could [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) it and remove [consecutive duplicates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: @bolov I edited my question. The PLY's are extect duplicates in terms of their Position (x,y) but no neccessarily in terms of their greyscale value.

Comment: also note that calculating the average of n integers (and store it in an integer )will lead to approximate result if their sum is not divisible by n

Comment: @JoachimPileborg can it be so that Kevin will end up with O(n*n) copy operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply lexicographical sorting first. During sorting you should take care of overflowing `greyscale`. With current approach you will have some roundoff error, but it will be small as i first sum and only then average.

In the second part you need to remove duplicates from the array. I used additional array of indices to copy every element not more than once. If you have some forbidden value for `x`, `y` or `greyscale` you can use it and thus get along without additional array.

```
struct PLY {
    int x;
    int y;
    int greyscale;
};

int main()
{
    struct comp
    {
        bool operator()(const PLY &a, const PLY &b) { return a.x != b.x ? a.x < b.x : a.y < b.y; }
    };
    vector<PLY> v{ {1,1,1}, {1,2,2}, {1,1,2}, {1,3,5}, {1,2,7} };
    sort(begin(v), end(v), comp());

    vector<bool> ind(v.size(), true);
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (v[i].x == v[i - 1].x &&v[i].y == v[i - 1].y)
        {
            v[s].greyscale += v[i].greyscale;
            ind[i] = false;
        }
        else
        {
            int d = i - s;
            if (d != 1)
            {
                v[s].greyscale /= d;
            }
            s = i;
        }
    }

    s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (ind[i])
        {
            if (s != i)
            {
                v[s] = v[i];
            }
            ++s;
        }
    }
    v.resize(s);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on your description of `Ply` you need these operators:

```
auto operator==(const Ply& a, const Ply& b)
{
  return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
}
auto operator<(const Ply& a, const Ply& b)
{
  // whenever you can be lazy!
  return std::make_pair(a.x, a.y) < std::make_pair(b.x, b.y);
}
```

Very important: if the definition "Two `Ply` are identical if their `x` and `y` are identical" is not general valid, then defining comparator operators that ignore `greyscale` is a bad ideea. In that case you should define separate function objects or non-operator functions and pass them around to function.

There is a nice rule of thumb that a function should not have more than a loop. So instead of a nested 2 `for` loops, we define this helper function which computes the average of consecutive duplicates and also returns the end of the consecutive duplicates range:

```
// prereq: [begin, end) has at least one element
//         i.e. begin != end
template <class It>
auto compute_average_duplicates(It begin, It end) -> std::pair<int, It>
   // (sadly not C++17) concepts:
   //requires requires(It i) { {*i} -> Ply; }
{
  auto it = begin + 1;
  int sum = begin->greyscale;
  for (; it != end && *begin == *it; ++it) {
    sum += it->greyscale;
  }
  // you might need rounding instead of truncation:
  return std::make_pair(sum / std::distance(begin, it), it);
}
```

With this we can have our algorithm:

```
auto foo()
{
  std::vector<Ply> v = {{1, 5, 10}, {2, 4, 6}, {1, 5, 2}};

  std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));

  for (auto i = std::begin(v); i != std::end(v); ++i) { 
    decltype(i) j;
    int average;

    std::tie(average, j) = compute_average_duplicates(i, std::end(v));

    // C++17 (coming soon in a compiler near you):
    // auto [average, j] = compute_average_duplicates(i, std::end(v));

    if (i + 1 == j)
      continue;

    i->greyscale = average;
    v.erase(i + 1, j);
    // std::vector::erase Invalidates iterators and references
    // at or after the point of the erase
    // which means i remains valid, and `++i` (from the for) is correct
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 but one thing; I'd avoid overloading `operator==` and `operator<` in this case; they doesn't take `greyscale` into account. It may cause confusion to other programmers or even to ourselves later time. Also, if we want to define another comparator that does consider `greyscale`, we are messed up.

Comment: @Ohashi I thought about that, but the OP said that by definition two `Ply` are identical if their `x` and `y` are. If that is not a general valid proposition, then yes non-operator comparators should be used instead.

Comment: This is n^2 no?  ... nope, just n lg n.  No wait n^2 due to your erase.  Erase can be fixed, behave like remove then erase tail.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to check, is `PLY a1 { 1,1,1 };` duplicates `PLY a2 {2,2,1};`
So simple method is to override `operator ==` to check `a1.x == a2.x` and `a1.y == a2.y`. After you can write own function `removeDuplicates(std::vector<PLU>& mPLY);` which will use *iterators* of this vector, compare and remove. But better to use `std::list` if you want to remove from middle of array too frequently.

Comment: Disagree with the last sentence: in this case removal may be done efficiently (in linear time) on the `std::vector` too (for example, refer the implementation of `std::remove_if`)

Comment: I edited my question and added an example for a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, your edited question is perfectly fit in my answer with iterator comparison.  
To remove from middle of list, you just need to switch pointers.  
To remove from vector, you need to shift full vector.   
Complexety `std::remove_if` of is Exactly `std::distance(first, last) `applications of the predicate.

Comment: @Warezovvv You mean comparing all pairs of elements in O(N^2) time? Consider also sorting the `vector` and using two pointers or using `std::unordered_map` to do this faster.